# Cloud access for NAS through a wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nas, cloud-storage, wireless-extender

Not long ago, my domestic partner's grandfather joined an assisted living community to better support his wife.

With trying to move his life from a house he lived in for 30+/- years, I've been left on tech duty, but have come across a doozy of an issue.

So he uses a Western Digital MyCloud NAS device to share information with his business partner across the world.  The assisted living facility has a group Wifi, and that's the entirety of connectivity. Obviously, connecting the NAS device directly to the NIC of the computer does not allow his business associate cloud connectivity.

As a work around, I got a Netgear N600 Wireless Range Extender - figured it would be an easy solution versus installing DD-WRT on a router and setting up a bridge.  Since he's not very tech-savvy, I figured this would be a simple solution.

Long story short - it's not.  The MyCloud device can be accessed through the Extender's network, but the Netgear device is not recognizing the MyCloud as a hard-wired device and thus not being assigned an IP address or being given access to the internet for cloud access.

I've updated the firmware for the Range Extender, changed the IP to static from Dynamic, and tried just about anything I can figure to do.

Anyone have any thoughts on making this configuration work?  Or am I going to have to just go the DD-WRT route?  If anyone has any other suggestions for configurations that could work I'd be happy to keep trying different things.  Budget is under $100.